# How to find all the root directories in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I am wondering how I can get all the top level directories in a MarkLogic database.

`cts:uris()` can be used for this purpose:

```
cts:uris()[matches(., '^[^/]*/$')]
```

But there must be something more efficient than matching every single URI to list a few top level directories!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you do not want to require directory properties and your definition of directories is that there exists a document with a URI that contains a "/" but does not end in a "/", xmlsh implements two implementations for this, neither 100% ideal - as there isnt a direct method.   Besides directory properties, the notion of "directory" is not a directly modeled concept in MarkLogic - similar to AWS S3 keys, its a derive convenience not a root concept.   To efficiently deduce the list of 'common prefixes' you will need the URI lexicon enabled.  THen you can make use of various URI search.   See

https://github.com/DALDEI/xmlsh/blob/master/extensions/marklogic/src/org/xmlsh/marklogic/ui/listRootDirectory.xquery

For an example of matching the 'directories' which under a root, or the top level 'directories' if $urimatch is "" .  This isnt perfect, but it does handle a common case where full URL's are being used as URI's in the database such as 'http://www.marklogic.com/document'

```
  declare variable $start external := 1 ;    
  declare variable $end  external := 1000;    
  declare variable $urimatch external := "" ;   
  fn:distinct-values(
    for $d in cts:uris("","any"  )
    where ($urimatch eq "" or contains( $d , $urimatch ) )

    return 
       if( matches( $d , "^[a-zA-Z]+://" ) ) then
          replace( $d , "(^[a-zA-Z]+://[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+/).*","$1" )
       else
       if( contains( $d , "/" ) ) then 
          substring-before( $d , "/" ) || "/"
       else 
        $d

    )[ $start to $end ]
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was expecting a built-in function implementing the same logic than behind functions such as [cts:directory-query()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:directory-query) and your solution is more generic than mine because it supports HTTP uris.

Comment: To summarize your answer, I'd say that to get the list of all "root directories" you do have to look at all existing URIs in a database and that the match pattern I have proposed is too weak because it would consider that the root directory of "http://example.com/foo.xml" is "http:/" while it should rather be "http://example.com/" is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get around pulling every URI. But, here is another method of getting a distinct list of root directories.

```
let $dir := (
          let $current := map:map()
          let $_ := map:put($current, "element", "")
          for $uri in cts:uris()
            let $toks := fn:tokenize($uri, "/")
            let $element :=  if (map:get($current, "element") ne $toks[2]) then  element directory { $toks[2] }  else ()
            let $_ := map:put($current, "element", $toks[2]) 
            return if ($element/text() ne "") then $element else  () 
    )

  let $doc := document { element root { $dir } }
  return $doc
```